# How to make button work after ajax called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In my project, I use the `seaStBt button` to open a search dialog.

I use AJAX to fetch data from the DB after I confirm the search dialog, which contains search conditions, and this data updates the `idcCstmRId div` successfully.

Here is the js code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
 { 
  $('#idcCstmRId').on("dblclick","#bbs td",function(){......});


  $('#seaStBt').click(function(){
    $('#dlgSea').dialog("open");
  });


  $('#seaBt').click(function(){
    var seaSlt1 = $('#seaSlt1').val();
    $.ajax({
        dataType:'html',
        type:"POST",
        url:"get_ajax_csc.php",
        data: {seaSlt1:seaSlt1},
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#idcCstmRId').html(data);
            $('#dlgSea').dialog("destroy").remove();
        }
    });     
  });
  ......
  }
 </script>
```

Here is html code:

```
 <div id="firDiv">  
 <?php
   echo '<table border=1px style="width:100%" id="bbs">';
  .......
 ?>
<div class="main_title" id="mnTlt">
<input type="button" id="seaStBt" value="search">
</div>
<div id="dlgSea" >
        <input type="submit" value="confirm" id="seaBt" />
</div>    
<div  class="idcCstmRqst" id="idcCstmRId"></div>
```

Here is get_ajax_csc.php code:

```
 if(isset($_POST['seaSlt1']))
{
    include("DB.php");
    $seaOne=$_POST['seaSlt1'];

    echo '<table border=1px style="width:100%" id="bbs">';
    ......
}
```

The problem is before fetching data from the DB, the `seaStBt button` displays search the dialog. But after fetching data, and `idcCstmRId div` updates successfully, the `seaStBt button` does not work any more. The search dialog does not show after clicking the `seaStBt button`.

Perhaps the AJAX changes the DOM, but `seaStBt button` sees does not see these changes?

I have no idea, who can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem could be with `.remove()` method.
jQuery docs says `.remove()` takes elements out of the DOM, so you are removing `#dlgSea`...

Comment: I use $('#dlgSea').dialog("destroy");  But unfortunately, #seaStBt also display nothing.

Comment: Are you using jQueryUI? If so, `.dialog("destroy")` will return the element back to its pre-init state (JqueryUI docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-destroy).
So, you have to re-init the dialog. Can't you simply use `.dialog( "close" )`?

Comment: .dialog( "close" ) works well, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to remove the click event from #seaStBt after the results are returned? If so, I believe you can do this with:

`$('#seaStBt').unbind('click');`

Comment: On the contrary, after the results are returned, #seaStBt keeps on clicking.